# Fastest way of comparing strings in C

Tags: c, string, compare, strcmp

I wanted to know if there are even faster ways of comparing strings in C than using `strcmp()`, especially when I have to compare a string with multiple pre-defined strings in a **switch statement** fashion. In my application, the string to be compared can sometimes go as big as 1000 chars, so was just thinking if `strcmp()` is sufficient enough or if there exists better and efficient way which I am not familiar with. I am actually working on a low power embedded IoT project where more CPU cycles cost power.

Comment: Is this a measured bottleneck in your code? Don't fall into the trap of premature optimizations.

Comment: What makes you think that even this macro of yours is "faster"? What makes you think any claims for "faster" are worth the fact that you're now facing all the potential troubles that come with multiple macro parameter expansion, and people scratching their heads about your non-standard solution to comparing strings?

Comment: That macro is not "nothing but `strcmp`". Before that,  `A` and `B` are evaluated for non-null test, and skips invoking `strcmp` and returns `0` if *either* are null. A bit misleading, considering if *both* are null they're certainly "equal", but still report `0`. Regardless, if string comparison is really the bottleneck, perhaps you'd be better off analyzing how to not do it as much rather than trying to optimize this thing.

Comment: Taking it one further... if string comparison is really at the *core* of your application, you'll probably want *real* string comparison, a.k.a. Unicode -- and then `strcmp()` doesn't cut it anyway. Besides, usually an application "knows" that `A` and `B` cannot be identical when comparing them; your extra check for that special case is making your code _slower_...

Comment: I'm not sure how this macro (which supposedly is just `strcmp` either way) is supposed to be faster than just using`strcmp`. If anything, you're tacking on that null comparison even in situations where you might not need it because they are guaranteed to be valid.

Comment: If the goal is to emulate a switch statement where the cases are hardcoded strings, then a hash map, or binary tree, or a trie are all possible options.

Comment: @DevSolar  I am not claiming that strcmp() enclosed in a macro is faster. My question just is, if there is anything faster than strcmp() itself. Added a note in the Question. I just wrote that kinda of a macro to just prevent comparison of a NULL pointed string pointer, nothing else.

Comment: @Akay: And we want to point out that the real question is, faster _at what_?

Comment: @DevSolar, faster in terms of latency, especially when I have to write in a switch statement kinda way

Comment: I still think you don't understand the issue here. Whether any given implementation of some functionality is "faster" than another depends heavily on the input data and usage profile. You should rely on `strcmp` being well-optimized for the general case. If your case is specific, you need to _specify the details of your case_. Your macro example does not really help, because it is not an "optimization" at all, but a *change* of the `strcmp` semantics -- an empty string now always compares equal to anything else. user3386109 has pointed to _potential_ candidates for specific case optimizations.

Comment: (ctd.) Regarding the title of your question, _for the general case_ it is safe to assume that `strcmp` is the fastest way of comparing strings in C. Specific cases might allow for different approaches. You'd need to show us that specific case then.

Comment: @DevSolar, ignore the macro, tell me if there is an even faster way to compare two strings just for EQUALITY. In my application, these strings can go as big as 1000 chars sometimes, so was just thinking if there is a faster way?

Comment: *sigh* -- _What is your actual problem?_ If you're about to write e.g. a parser (and are currently working on a `switch` that tests input tokens against multiple keywords), the "correct" answer would probably be to point you toward parser generators like `bison`. If you have perhaps "forgotten" about the intricacies of non-ASCII and locales, we should point you to `strcoll` or `strxfrm`. You might benefit (as user2286109 pointed out) from hashes, binary trees, or tries. _We don't know._

Comment: (ctd.) Please. Either specify the actual problem, or accept that _for the general case_ it is safe to assume that `strcmp` is the fastest way of comparing two strings in C. Voting to close as "unclear what you're asking". (And to come full circle to the very first comment, _make sure you actually have a problem that needs optimization._)

Comment: Thanks @user3386109, well from the discussion it looks like strcmp() itslef is well optimized and the fastest. I will certainly look more into hash map, or binary tree, or a trie.

Comment: hash map can be faster than binary tree here, trie could be fastest if likely to not have matches...

Comment: @DevSolar, I have modified the question, let me know if it is clear, or you want me to delete it? I accept it was a bit unclear previously, my bad :(

Comment: It still isn't really clear. There _may_ be lots of ways to implement things more efficiently, but it isn't really about "a faster `strcmp`" but rather about "this is my construct, can I optimize it?". We don't know how your input will usually look like, or what your "1000 character strings" look like. How many of those strings you have, how many comparisons are done on average. (This would allow calculating if the number of comparisons would outweigh the cost of calculating a hash for the input.) Optimization is a _complex_ art, and very much specific to the individual task.

Comment: (ctd.) Perhaps a simple reordering of the checks would do wonders. Perhaps a multi-tiered approach depending on the first letter(s) of the input. Perhaps a tree structure. _Perhaps._ There *can* be no generic answer.

Comment: @DevSolar Sure, I will try doing that way :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't sound as if the problem has as much to do with `strcmp` itself, as how you use it.

The fastest way to compare strings against a table of pre-defined strings, is to ensure that the strings are sorted alphabetically, then use binary search. Where `strcmp` acts as the comparison function. C standard `bsearch` may or may not be feasible on an embedded system. Otherwise, it is fairly simple to implement yourself.

That is, unless the number of strings are vast. Then at some point, some manner of hash table will perform better than searching. To give an exact answer of what performs best, one needs all the details of the data.

With fixed-length strings you can improve performance ever so slightly by using `memcmp` instead - that way you don't have to check against null termination. But that's really a micro-optimization.

Comment: A hash table would probably be even faster.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Generally, yes, unless this is a limited amount of strings. A hash table has almost random access time, but calling the hash function gives a bit of overhead. Typically it contains division/modulus etc which might chew up a fair amount of CPU cycles. So it isn't obvious where exactly the hash table starts to out-perform binary search, only that it eventually will, at table size "x" and beyond.